# Using a PDA, show that ( x * y ) + x is a valid string

Tags: string, math, logic, discrete-mathematics, pushdown-automaton

[image: image of question]

im having trouble with part C if you could assist me with it and explain how its done as well. thanks you in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and refer to the [help/on-topic] for topics you can ask about here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: IIRC, "PDA" means *pushdown automata* in this context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a CS theory question, which is a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Weird question. To use a PDA you'd have to define one first, not sure how that shows anything's valid.

Answer (score 0):

(a) As far as I can tell they're just asking that the grammar be rewritten:

```
<E> -> <E> + <T>
<E> -> <E> - <T>
<E> -> <T>
<T> -> <T> * <F>
<T> -> <T> / <F>
<T> -> <F>
<F> -> (<F>)
<F> -> x
<F> -> y
```

(b) They want a derivation of (x * y) + x:

```
                          (             <T> -- <F> -- x
                         /             /
                        /             /
                       /             /
      <E> -- <T> -- <F> -- <E> -- <T> -- *
     /                 \             \
    /                   \             \
   /                     \             \
<E> -- +                  )             <F> -- y
   \
    \
     \
      <T> -- <F> -- x
```

(c) we can define a NPDA which nondeterministically pushes all valid derivations onto the stack then pops off the input in order to accept. The stack would look like this:

```
stack         input remaining
Z             (x * y) + x
<E>Z          (x * y) + x
<E>+<T>Z      (x * y) + x
<T>+<T>Z      (x * y) + x
<F>+<T>Z      (x * y) + x
(<E>)+<T>Z     x * y) + x
<E>)+<T>Z      x * y) + x
<T>)+<T>Z      x * y) + x
<T>*<F>)+<T>Z  x * y) + x
<F>*<F>)+<T>Z  x * y) + x
x*<F>)+<T>Z    x * y) + x
*<F>)+<T>Z       * y) + x
<F>)+<T>Z          y) + x
y)+<T>Z            y) + x
)+<T>Z              ) + x
+<T>Z                 + x
<T>Z                    x
<F>Z                    x
xZ                      x
Z                 (empty)
```